# Android 2.3 Music Player Source Code

Tags: android, android-music-player

Where can I find Source Code for Gingerbread 2.3/2.3.2 Music Player Source Code?
I have been searching on GitHub but didn't get any. Is there any other Music Player Source Code for referencing purpose?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23532471/2751529

Answer (score 2):

Officially, the source of android is in https://android.googlesource.com

The music player source can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Music.git)

Comment: Is there any other Music Player Source Code which I can refer other than the Stock ones?

Comment: I is there any other Music Player Source other than the official ones?